# General solution of $yy'' - (y')^2 + y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you derive the general solution of
$$ y y'' - (y')^2 + y' = 0 $$
Thanks.

======

Never mind.  Solved.

Let $u = y'$.  Then $y'' = u' = \frac{du}{dy}$ . $y' = \frac{du}{dy} . u$

Hence the equation is
$$ yu \cdot\frac{du}{dy} = u^2 - u $$
which is separable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Divide everything by $y^2$. Then use the identities 
$$
\left(\dfrac{y'}y\right)'=\dfrac{y''y-(y')^2}{y^2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\left(\dfrac1y\right)'=\dfrac{-y'}{y^2}.
$$

Comment: Note that $y=0$ is a solution too. You may lose it after division.

Comment: That's elegant.  Thanks.